# Cannot add Enterprise Admins to a Group via Box.com API

Tags: box-api

It seems I'm not allowed to add an Enterprise Admin or Co-Admin to a group via the API.  I can add all other types of users to groups, and can create/edit/delete groups just fine, but I'm not allowed to add a user to a group if that user is an Enterprise Admin or Co-Admin.

Is this expected behavior, or is my application user missing some sort of entitlement?

```
POST /group_memberships
{ "user": { "id": "12345"}, "group": { "id": "12345" } }


{
  "type":"error",
  "status":403,
  "code":"access_denied_insufficient_permissions",
  "help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors",
  "message":"Access denied - insufficient permission",
  "request_id":"xxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Box has restrictions on manipulating groups via the API. I've been told that your app may have to request the Manage an Enterprise permission.

Comment: The application does have the Manage an Enterprise entitlement set on it already, which is how I can create and manage groups for the most part. Its just admin users that I'm not allowed to add to a group.

Answer (score 0):

This is the box a limitation/feature. You can not add an Enterprise Admin or Co-Admin to the group of another Administrator.

For example:

User A and B are enterprise admins. Each sing up to box separately. 
When user A create a group, he can create a new user and add the created user to the group.

But user A can not add the user B to the group.

Likewise, when user B create a group, he can not add the user A.

Because they are from different organizations.

You will clear when you try to add an Enterprise Admin to the group via https://app.box.com website. If you do so, the pop up will show with the message "The supplied email address already has a Box account that belongs to a different organization."